# How do I login as the root user?

Tags: linux, shell, sudo, users, su

I installed Debian a day ago and I'm very new to Linux please forgive me if I miss something obvious but:
whenever I use sudo command it asks me for the current user password but the current user doesn't have permission to use sudo so I have to use su and run my command there but the command I installed there only works there not in my user I used popos before and I think I was the root user there because sudo worked fine how do I login as root? In my login page (sddm) there is only 1 user.

**EDIT:** Can I somehow don't make a normal user in the installation? what if I leave the normal user password and username empty? will there only be root user that I can login with?

Comment: It looks like you do but just to be clear, do you know the root password?

Comment: @NasirRiley yes I know, I made it

Comment: What version of Debian are you using?

Comment: @NasirRiley Debian 11

Comment: "_Can I somehow don't make a normal user in the installation_" that would be a really bad idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on how you've setup your system at installation.
If you've created a root account by entering a password for the root account during installation you can switch to a different tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login as root from there.

You can then give your users account the permission to escalate privileges via sudo.

#### give user privileges to run sudo

##### add user to sudo group

Debian is by default configured to allow all members of the `sudo` group to use the `sudo` privilege escalation.

The simplest way would be to add your user to the `sudo` group via `usermod -aG sudo yourusername`

##### /etc/sudoers file

You can also edit the `sudoers` file. Note that you should never edit this file manually, it could render your system unusable. Instead use `visudo` as it checks the file for errors after editing.

1. run `visudo`
2. add `yourusername    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` to the end of the file
3. close and save the file via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: But then I have no GUI. How should I set it up to make something like popos? I will reinstall it like that

Comment: What do you mean by "make something like popos"?

Comment: I'm the root user there and sudo works fine and I can use apt and other things

Comment: Well, I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. You don't need to use `sudo` as the root user, but you might want to add your user to the `sudo` group to give your user the privileges to run `sudo`.

Comment: Ok, I add ```myuser    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL``` to visudo but now what's the usage of root user? It feels like something is wrong

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't help you with your feelings.  The root user is completely normal on a linux distribution, but might be disabled on mainstream desktop distros .

Comment: No, I'm sorry I missed something I just learned what root and su and sudo means

Comment: No need to be sorry, I'm glad to be a part of your learning journey. Just note that for your next question here you might want to add the command you are trying to run and the error message additionally to your explanation. This makes it easier for others to understand your problem right away and chances are better for a quality answer.